# TD rowspan not working

Tags: html, html-table

I have the table:

```
<table id="Table_05" width="675" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  
style="display:block">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_14.jpg" width="70" 
height="49" alt=""></td>
<td valign="top"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_12.jpg" width="410" 
height="21" alt="">
<td valign="bottom"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_15.jpg" width="410" 
height="29" alt=""></td>
<td rowspan="2"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_13.jpg" width="195" 
height="50" alt=""></td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It is supposed to be 3 columns table where second and third td are in one column. However, now it is in 2 columns.

Comment: please provide an image for what you have trying to do exactly.

Comment: Its obvious, she wants 2 tds in one and the same row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might create new table in the TD with 2 rows.

```html
<table id="Table_05" width="675" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: block;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/70/49" width="70" height="49" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="410">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/410/21" width="410" height="21" alt="" />
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="bottom">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/410/29" width="410" height="29" alt="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/195/50" width="195" height="50" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 11):

Check your CSS

This prevents you to span:

```
td { display: inline-block; }
```

Another case according to Simon_Weaver as per later comment:

```
{ display: flex}
```

Answer (score 6):

You used `rowspan="2"` on the first and last . Rowspan means that this cell spans two rows. If you want the cell to span over two columns in the same row, you have to use the `colspan` property. Check out the two snippets to see the difference:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
</tr>
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to close the second `<td />` tag.

Answer (score 1):

As mpcabd says in their answer, you're missing the `</td>` tag at the end of the second `<td>`

However, another issue is that you don't have a 2nd row for the `rowspan="2"` to go into.

My guess is you're after this...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><img ... /></td>
    <td><img .. /></td>
    <td rowspan="2"><img .. /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Note, you don't need anything here, as the rowspan will take it's place -->
    <td><img .. /></td>
    <!-- Note, you don't need anything here, as the rowspan will take it's place -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td rowspan="2">d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oc9vabvx/

Answer (score 0):

The second image must be on the next line. By the rowspan=2 of the first column it will be added to the second column:

```
<table id="Table_05" width="675" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  
       style="display:block">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_14.jpg" width="70" 
         height="49" alt=""></td>
    <td valign="top"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_12.jpg" width="410" 
        height="21" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_13.jpg" width="195" 
     height="50" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><img src="images/12235_PLUS_mail_August_v4_15.jpg" width="410" 
        height="29" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```